# Problem with removing white padding edges on iframe

Tags: html, iframe, padding

I have a problem with removing the white border on the edge of an `iframe`. In this `html` code, I have a button that sends you to a blank tab when clicked.

I have made multiple attempts to remove the white padding edges.
Here is the base code without me trying to remove the padding;
https://jsfiddle.net/4dchkyqt/

Some of the code I tried adding to fix it; `iframe.style.margin = "none";` and `iframe.style.padding = "0"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white border is on the page that holds the `iFrame` - You need to set it's `body` attribute of `margin: 0;` -

For example, add `win.document.body.style.margin = '0';` in your script before you append the `iFrame` to the `document`